# Difference between mkdir and mkdir -p?

Tags: powershell, command-line

I've been following Learn Code the Hard Way's tutorial on learning how to utilize the command line interface in PowerShell. In [this](http://cli.learncodethehardway.org/book/cli-crash-coursech8.html) article, it tells me to use the command `mkdir -p i\like\icecream`. At the bottom, it explains "`mkdir -p` will make an entire path even if all the directories don't exist."

I'm confused, as `mkdir i\like\icecream` without the `-p` argument still does the same thing. I've experimented and done stuff such as creating a "one" directory, then creating "one\two\three" with `mkdir` and it will automatically create a two directory for three to be placed in. Does PowerShell automatically assume `-p` or something in cases like this? I'm at a loss as to what this argument does.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

PowerShell does its best to determine what parameter you mean even if you don't give it fully. Thus if you use the `-p` parameter, you are actually using `-path`.

For the mkdir function, the `-path` parameter tells the function the path to create. `-path` is also by default the first argument to the function if no explicit parameters are provided. So calling the function with `-p` (`-path`) and without `-p` are exactly the same thing as far as the function is concerned.

For more information, in the shell type:

```
Get-Help mkdir
```

I will also clarify that when you call mkdir, what you are really doing is calling the New-Item cmdlet and specifying the -ItemType parameter as Directory. That is why you see the New-Item help when you run that command. If you want to see the actual code for the mkdir function to see how it does this, do this:

```
(get-command mkdir).ScriptBlock
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. The tutorial had previously only had me using `mkdir`, then it threw out the `-p` thing which didn't appear to do anything different. Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: I think the `-p` comes from a confusion with the *nix variant of `mkdir`, which indeed acts differently on `-p`, which will, as the tutorial suggests, create any missing parent folders as well.

Comment: The powershell team made a concerted effort to provide aliases and functions with names that would make *nix admins more comfortable. Sometimes I suppose it can add some confusion as well.

Comment: "(get-command mkdir).ScriptBlock" did not return anything when I tried it (PowerShell 2.0, Windows 7).

Answer (score 0):

If we create a directory using,

- mkdir, mkdir will throw an exception if the directory already exists,so we need to check 
  before creating a directory over same path

whereas

- mkdirp, mkdirp always checks automatically if the directory exists or not over the 
  specified path, hence no need to implement any check.